# Help with understanding the sentence

Tags: grammar

I saw this sentence in the book "How to Read a Book".

> “There is the book, and here is your mind. As you go through the pages, either you understand perfectly everything the author has to say or you do not. If you do, you may have gained information, but you could not have increased your understanding. If the book is completely intelligible to you from start to finish, then the author and you are as two minds in the same mold. **The symbols on the page merely express the common understanding you had before you met.**”

Does the highlighted part simply mean: the common understanding you had before? How to understand this grammar structure?

I think I understand what the author is trying to say, but I am curious how this grammar works.

Thanks

Comment: More context is needed. In general terms, I believe it's simply saying that all symbols are meaningless unless you already know what they mean. If I've never seen the *@* symbol before, and I see it on a page, it will be gibberish.

Comment: It means:  Whatever you knew or understood before you hooked up with X

Comment: The preceding context is ***essential*** here, since the point being made is *extremely* non-intuitive! The writer is discussing a hypothetical idealised context where the reader already knows ***everything*** that the writer knows (so actually *reading* the text is completely pointless). But to be honest, I think that's such an obscure / impossible scenario that it's not helpful. The person who wrote the text we're looking at here ***is not a good writer***, imho.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to interpret some poorly-written text that doesn't even reflect a possible reality.

Comment: I have added more context to the original question. The sentence is an excerpt from the book "How to Read a Book". I think I understand what the author is trying to say, but I am curious how this grammar works.

Comment: [link to the book](https://www.amazon.com/Revised-Updated-Mortimer-Aug-15-1972-Paperback/dp/B005O89RBQ/ref=pd_sbs_14_5/135-2761744-1044016?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B005O89RBQ&pd_rd_r=a120d34c-9d13-4c78-9e16-e1c6b0415ee0&pd_rd_w=rttlL&pd_rd_wg=VpLtT&pf_rd_p=d28ef93e-22cf-4527-b60a-90c984b5663d&pf_rd_r=B25FF0ZZF5X9JR5H0Q0A&psc=1&refRID=B25FF0ZZF5X9JR5H0Q0A)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think you are correct in the sense that the author is indeed trying to describe a very bad situation in reading/writing. Could you help with understanding the grammar with the additional context?

Comment: Personally, I think the highlighted text is both poorly-written AND ill-thought-through. One particularly irritating aspect from my point of view is that the writer is clearly addressing "you" (his target *reader*) as a ***singular*** entity initially. But at some point within the parsing of the shared knowledge ***you had before you met***, we have to switch mental gears and recognise that we're now talking about a ***plural*** "you". Where the *other* person is "the author" (but presumably not the ***current*** author! :) It's just hopelessly woolly thinking, imho.

Comment: ...that's to say, in this hypothetical scenario, you know everything "the author" knows. So any text he writes tells you nothing you didn't already know. You don't know any more after reading the words than you did before you (metaphorically) ***met*** this author by picking up his book and reading it. Look again at the highlighted words and see whether you understand them differently if you replace either or both instances of ***you*** with explicitly plural ***you two*** (or ***youse*** if you understand Texans! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Your explanation is very helpful, thank you!